# Category Custom Attribute in rest API in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, category, rest-api

I am using **magento 2.2.7** and I am creating **rest API** for Category. From swagger I am getting value like:

```
{
"id": 28,
"parent_id": 2,
"name": "Smart Phones",
"is_active": true,
 "position": 1,
"level": 2,
"children": "",
"created_at": "2018-11-03 01:32:45",
"updated_at": "2019-01-14 06:33:52",
"path": "1/2/28",
"available_sort_by": [],
"include_in_menu": true,
"custom_attributes": [
  {
    "attribute_code": "display_mode",
  "value": "PRODUCTS"
},
{
  "attribute_code": "is_anchor",
  "value": "1"
},
{
  "attribute_code": "path",
  "value": "1/2/28"
},
{
  "attribute_code": "children_count",
  "value": "0"
},
{
  "attribute_code": "custom_use_parent_settings",
  "value": "0"
},
{
  "attribute_code": "custom_apply_to_products",
  "value": "0"
},
{
  "attribute_code": "url_key",
  "value": "smart-phones"
},
{
  "attribute_code": "url_path",
  "value": "smart-phones"
},

{
  "attribute_code": "tamil",
  "value": "பேக்குகள் & லக்கேஜ்"
},
{
  "attribute_code": "telugu",
  "value": "బ్యాగ్స్ & లగేజీ"
}
]
}
```

In which  **`"attribute_code":`** **`"telugu"`**, and   **`"attribute_code":`** **`"tamil"`**, is **`custom attribute`**. and it is coming inside the **`custom Attribute array`**.
I want this parameter outside of custom attribute along with **NAME** and **ID**. 
Please help me to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot change this structure on existing API.If you want to do this then you have to build custom API point.

Comment: yes, in custom API only, how to achieve this?

Comment: Why you don't want to fetch data from `custom Attribute array`.? As per as Magento standard very custom data  and third party related data should be inside of  `custom_attributes` and `extension_attribute`  .I guess that your app developer tell you to provide d?ata in this way!!!! Why they donot fetch data from inside from `custom Attribute array`

Comment: yes, you are right, they want like that only, so i have to restructure API